# Am I doing something wrong with Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm building a simple game using React, following [this book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/modern-full-stack-development/9781484257388/). This app uses Typescript for both the client and the server, with the addition of Webpack for the client side.

I've followed all the steps, installed all the dependencies and wrote the code for every single file and in the end I'm having problems with the rendering of one component. I've downloaded the source code and it works perfectly, and I can assure you that mine is exactly the same but while the source one works, mine doesn't.

The only differences are that my packages are newer compared with those used in the source app, and that  when I run the command `npx webpack` I get this result with my app:

```
 ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.7.3 from typescript
i ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from D:/Programmazione/Typescript/BattleJong/client/tsconfig.json
i ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
i ｢atl｣: Time: 2615ms
asset main.js 1.15 MiB [compared for emit] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset ./index.html 190 bytes [compared for emit]
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
modules by path ./src/ 148 KiB
  modules by path ./src/img/*.png 113 KiB 42 modules
  modules by path ./src/code/ 31.4 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./src/css/*.css 4.21 KiB
    ./src/css/main.css 1.13 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/main.css 3.07 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./node_modules/ 999 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.75 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 26.3 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/normalize.css/*.css 16.1 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 70.6 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 875 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.94 KiB 2 modules
  + 1 module
webpack 5.70.0 compiled successfully in 6120 ms
```

and when I do it in the source app it comes off like this:

```
i ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.7.3 from typescript
i ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from D:/Download/Battlejong/client/tsconfig.json
i ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
i ｢atl｣: Time: 1203ms
Hash: 863163bcf3e0b4eccb1e
Version: webpack 4.41.3
Time: 4208ms
Built at: 10/03/2022 21:23:42
       Asset       Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
./index.html  192 bytes          [emitted]
     main.js    266 KiB       0  [emitted]        [big]  main
 main.js.map    489 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]         main
Entrypoint main [big] = main.js main.js.map
 [4] ./src/code/main.tsx 631 bytes {0} [built]
 [7] ./src/css/main.css 466 bytes {0} [built]
 [8] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/main.css 1.53 KiB {0} [built]
[17] ./src/img/tile101.png 5.59 KiB {0} [built]
[18] ./src/img/tile102.png 3.15 KiB {0} [built]
[19] ./src/img/tile103.png 2.58 KiB {0} [built]
[20] ./src/img/tile104.png 1.14 KiB {0} [built]
[21] ./src/img/tile105.png 2.39 KiB {0} [built]
[22] ./src/img/tile106.png 2.1 KiB {0} [built]
[23] ./src/img/tile107.png 3.49 KiB {0} [built]
[24] ./src/img/tile108.png 2.53 KiB {0} [built]
[25] ./src/img/tile109.png 2.53 KiB {0} [built]
[26] ./src/img/tile110.png 2.29 KiB {0} [built]
[27] ./src/img/tile111.png 1.58 KiB {0} [built]
[59] ./src/code/state.ts 12.3 KiB {0} [built]
    + 46 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 175 bytes {0} [built]
```

It seems to me that there are problems with my build of Webpack, because I don't get all those `[build]`.

My Webpack config is really simple:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/code/main.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                use: {loader: "url-loader",
                    options: { limit: 65536, esModule: false, }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: { loader: "html-loader" }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader" ]
            },
            {
                test: /.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html", 
        filename: "./index.html"})
    ],
    performance: { hints: false },
    watch: true,
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

So should I change something? Or maybe commands are changed?

Comment: What version of webpack is specified in your `package.json`?

Comment: In my package.json the version is 5.70.0, and in the source file is 4.41.3